# Wildfly database form-login module failure in production

Tags: jsf, wildfly, managed-bean, wildfly-8

For a while I developed my Wildfly 8.1 web application on localhost (Windows 8.1) and wanted to deploy to my Ubuntu Server to Wildfly 8.2.

Local form login works with a ManagedBean, but on my production server it fails. Why?

- Database connection works.

Thus, I imply it hase something to do with the form-login configured in my standalone.xml file. Which apparently is THE VERY SAME as on my localhost standalone.xml file. I checked, the Wildfly 8.2 on production is truely using this standalone.xml file! Executing the principals query against the production database (the same vendor and version as on my localhost) returns exactly 1 row. Same as in my local dev environment.

But why does this `principalsQuery` login-module not work in production? Anyone any clue?

```
<login-module code="Database" flag="required">
    <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/CcmsDS"/>
    <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT password FROM User WHERE username=?"/>
    <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT role, 'Roles' FROM User JOIN User_Role ON User.id = User_Role.users_id JOIN role ON User_Role.roles_id = Role.id WHERE username=?"/>
</login-module>
```

Can I anyhow output the exact cause on my prodcution server's log?

Here is the ManagedBean code:

```
        try {
            request.login(getUsername(), getPassword());            
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            LOGGER.info("Failed to login with username " + username + " and password. " + e.getMessage() + ". ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Login failed",
                    "Login failed when trying to authenticate with user " + getUsername() + "."));
            // If this fails, return null.
            return null;
        }
```

... and here the error message from the HttpServletRequestImpl:

```
2015-04-05 23:03:06,320 ERROR [stderr] (default task-12) L:71 javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010031: Login failed
2015-04-05 23:03:06,320 ERROR [stderr] (default task-12) L:71   at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.login(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:440)
2015-04-05 23:03:06,321 ERROR [stderr] (default task-12) L:71   at com.johndoe.controller.security.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:239)
```

Comment: Resolution: The  rolesQuery was not case sensitive (Windows --> Ubuntu). I corrected it, and the prinicipals query worked. No clue why they are interconnected. Hope this helps someone else, too.

Comment: I can't see where you state what database server you are using, by for mysql, the table names are case sensitive as filenames are case sensitive on Linux but not on Windows

Answer (score 1):

Resolution: The rolesQuery was not case sensitive (Windows --> Ubuntu). I corrected it, and the prinicipals query worked. No clue why they are interconnected. Hope this helps someone else, too.